# Google play game services integration after new update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

> **Important**: The Play Games services APIs have been revised to support the simplified Google API client programming model for Google
>   Play services. The previous Games client is deprecated as of February
>   7th, 2014. Existing and new developers are strongly encouraged to use
>   GoogleApiClient instead of the deprecated GamesClient.

I have properly imported `google-play-services_lib`, `BaseGameUtils` and linked everything properly, but imports like this, no longer work:

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
```

`The import com.google.android.gms.games.Games can not be resolved`

I am having real trouble integrating Google Play Services with GamesClient deprecated. All the online resources for implementation haven't been revised to the new model.
This is my first game with Google play services and i have become extremely frustrated as a result from days of failure, can someone shine a little clarity on the new programming model and how to implement it?

Comment: Every tutorial on the [official site](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) has been updated to the new model so I'm not sure what you mean by 'all the online resources for implementation haven't been revisted to the new model'?

Comment: I dont think all samples online from Google have been updated - an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239750/error-getgamesclient-not-defined-trying-to-run-googles-sample-game

Comment: @ianhanniballake indeed, there are some which are not updated

Comment: @ılǝ - can you point out which ones remain to be updated? user1406716's example was updated a month ago (along with the others).

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think "ButtonClicker", "SkeletonTemp" and "EndlessTunnel". There are still imports of `GamesClient` in them - http://bit.ly/1j2I0y8

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest google Play Service Library and in it `import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;`   works..so you have to update your google play service library

Comment: Is this related?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239750/error-getgamesclient-not-defined-trying-to-run-googles-sample-game