# Error: "getGamesClient() not defined" - trying to run Google's Sample Game

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to run the Google Game Play Services example from [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/8BitArtist).

I have added Google Play services (latest rev 15) and BaseGameUtils as library projects to my project, as instructed. I have no error except the following: "The method getGamesClient() is undefined ..."

I think I am missing some library reference? Any help is appreciated. My setup screenshots are below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like that the 8bitartist sample has not been updated with the new API googleApiClient() references.

I edited the 'getGamesClient()' using the code samples here: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/commit/c2e6a2d66abaece3404f6a7b0e36e634470aca5d